# EmptyDataText and EmptyDataTemplate in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, message, emptydatatext

I have this code on a gridview

```
   <asp:GridView ID="ReconcileGridView" runat="server" EmptyDataText="Please Select Transaction Month And Date" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#4A3C8C" BorderWidth="3px" GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid"
                CellPadding="3" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="ReconcileGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                OnRowDataBound="ReconcileGridView_RowDataBound"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ReconcileGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                  <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <center>
                        No Record Found
                    </center>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

            </asp:GridView>
```

The Problem is on page Load i want the word **Please Select Transaction Month And Date** to appear and when a user inputs the a transaction month and date and no data was retrieved 
**No Record Found** should show, how would i do that? on the code above only the word **No Record Found** shows, i Databind Empty Data on page load to make those messages appear.

please help on making that happen.

Comment: The **EmptyDataText** property and the **EmptyDataTemplate** are alternatives to doing the same exact thing: to display a message when the data source that is bound to the control does not contain any records. So, in your case one simply overrides the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place a separate Label control for word **Please Select Transaction Month And Date**
and on page load, you have to set the label control visible property true
and when user inputs the month and date then you can set the lable control property false.

make sense?

Answer (score -1):

You have to place a separate Label control for "Please Select Transaction Month And Date" and on page load, you have to set the label control visible property true and when user inputs the month and date then you can set the label control property false.

Make sure not to bind your Gridview in the page load.

If you are placing the Gridview in an update panel and binding to null to clear it, then the EmptyDataTemplate will be shown. You most likely want to label to shown and not the EmptyDataTemplate. So you will need to hide the entire GridView (if not displaying headers) or you will need to add a cssClass to hide the EmptyDataTemplate at the appropriate points in the codebehind (alternatively use javascript).